# How to fix trouble with urls better django

Tags: python, django

I have a section residential interiors on the site, so the typical url looks like this https://caparolcenterspb.ru/decision/livingrooms/kitchen/provans/ (room and style)

However different rooms may have the same styles and when searching for styles in views.py it may output several styles and an error

views.py

```
selected_room = Room.objects.get(slug=rmslg)
 style = Style.objects.get(slug=stslg)
```

When you try to replace slug with different styles depending on the room(for example, provans_kitchen), an error occurs in the template(just put provans by default will not work)

residentialInteriors.html

```
{% for room in all_rooms %}
                <li class="menu__item menu__item_interiors"><a href="{% url 'decision:style' rmslg=room.slug stslg='provans' %}">{{ room.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
```

I have 2 solution ideas(preferably 2):

1. either change stslg in template by default to 'provans_' + str(room. slug), but this line does not work(especially not the fact that provans will be everywhere)
2. either search for style in views.py not only for stslg, but also for rmslg, but for this in the style model, you need to create a room field inherited from the room model, which also does not work for me, since Room is declared further than Style

models.py

```
class Style(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/')
    walls = models.TextField()
    floor = models.TextField()
    roof = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Стили'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Стили'

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    styles = models.ManyToManyField(Style)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комнаты'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комнаты'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the relation field that you already have on `Room` 
to only find styles associated with the given room?

```
selected_room = Room.objects.get(slug=rmslg)
style = selected_room.styles.get(slug=stslg)
```

Comment: yeah, that's true. In my opinion this is the best way